# What is the difference between these two angles?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Sorry for my bad grammar:

ABCD is a square and BDE is a right triangle where the angle BED is the right angle and ACF is BDE but rotated(They have the same angles and side lengths and AFC is the right angle) and a line connects E and F and it is NOT the bisector.
What's the difference between the angles E1 and F1?
The shape:

[image]

Comment: I think you should include a sketch

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan I know but Inhave less than 10 reputations. What should I do?

Comment: You do not need reputations to create a sketch

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan  You do need sufficient rep to upload the image and have it render in a post.  However, the OP can include a link to the image, which some editor will likely be able to render the image inside the post.

Comment: OK but you need to clarify what angles you are discussing.  For example, I assume that points E and F are INSIDE the square??  Your description does not require this.  Your description also does not adequately define angles F1 and E1.

Comment: If angle $\angle BED$ is a right angle, then $BD$ is the hypotenuse of the triangle $\triangle BED.$ But the convention for naming a square is you take the vertices in either clockwise or counterclockwise order. So $BD$ would be a diagonal of a square named $ABCD,$ not a side of the square. A drawing would clarify what you meant to say. I suspect the way you named the square is non-standard.

Comment: Are $E=E_1$ and $F=F_1$? Why the index $1$?

Answer (score 0):

Draw the circle of diameter $AC$: point $F$ belongs to it (you should know why) and the center $O$ of the square also lies on it.

But line $EF$, by symmetry, passes through $O$. Hence inscribed angles $\angle AFO$ and $\angle CFO$ both subtend a quarter of the circle and are thus congruent. The same applies to $\angle DEO$ and $\angle BEO$.

Here's a diagram made with GeoGebra. Notice that triangle $BED$ is obtained by rotating $ACF$ by $180°$ about $O$, hence line $EF$ passes through $O$. If $BED$ were oriented the other way, then it couldn't be a rotated copy of $ACF$, as stated in the question.

[image]

Comment: But I believe they are not the same size since if you rotate ACF , F1 would NOT be put on E1.

Comment: I'd suggest you to draw the diagram with GeoGebra and see what happens.

Comment: I added an animated diagram made with [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org): I hope it's of help.